# (c# refactor) Wrapper delegator - How to call Interface method as parameter

Tags: c#, refactoring, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I've to refactor old code that use a wrapper delegator for a service. This is old code:

```
public interface IOrderService
{
    IList<Order> GetOrders();
    Order GetOrderById(int idOrder);
}

public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    ... //Implements interface
}

//this is a simple delegate to OrderServiceReferenceClient
public class OrderServiceWcfWrapper : IOrderService
{
    IOrderService _Proxy;
    public OrderServiceWcfWrapper()
    {
        //some initializzation
        _proxy = new OrderServiceReferenceClient(); // WCF service reference
    }

    public IList<Order> GetOrders()
    {
        return _proxy.GetOrders();
    }
    public Order GetOrderById(int idOrder)
    {
        return _proxy.GetOrderById(idOrder);
    }
}
```

From Client service Layer, this service is called from wrapper because application can be off-line or on-line: online the application access to WCF implementation, offline access to local implementation:

```
public class ServiceWrapper
{
    public static IOrderService OrderService
    {
        get
        {
            if (ApplicationHelper.IsOffline)
                return new OrderService();

            return new OrderServiceWcfWrapper()
        }
    }
}

//from client
var order5 = ServiceWrapper.OrderService.GetOrderById(5);
```

I'd like to refactor this code with some like stategy pattern, and use a generic "something" becouse I've 12 services and I'd like to save to write 12 wrapper for WCF (see OrderServiceWcfWrapper). This is my idea:

```
public interface IWrapper<T>
{
    //object Invoke<T>();
}
public class ServiceFactory<T>
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ServiceFactory<T>));
    private T _service;

    public static IWrapper<T> CreateWrapper()
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsInterface)
            throw new ApplicationException("You must create a service from an interface. Use an interface as generics parameter");

        log.Debug("stato off-line= " + OnlineOfflineManager.Instance.IsOffline.ToString());

        //resolve implementation from local dictionary or IoC container
        return DependencyFactory.GetInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

I'd like to user my ServiceFactory like this:

```
   var wrapper = ServiceFactory<IOrderService>.CreateWrapper()
   var order5 = wrapper.Invoke(x => x.GetOrderById(5))
```

How can I resolve "Invoke" method?
There are other solution?

Comment: Maybe just implement `IOrderService` on your `OrderServiceReferenceClient`? Then you don't need to write that wrapper.

Comment: @Evk OrderServiceReferenceClient already implements IOrderService. I've to use wrapper becouse I must do some operation on WCF channel

Comment: Does `OrderServiceReferenceClient` inherit from some base class? If yes - it that base class enough to perform that operation you need to do on wcf channel?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the [circuit breaker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/implement-circuit-breaker-pattern) pattern.